# Play Framework 2.3 handling Future in Controllers

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a controller that exposes a method as a route. In this method, I call a long running computation that returns a Future[SomeType].

I now have the following:

```
  def compute(id: String) = Action.async { request =>
    val result: Future[SomeType] = compute(id)
    result.map(value => Ok(transform(value, id)))
  }
```

So far this is just the happy path. What if compute(id) results in a Failure? How to handle that? I could wrap the whole thing in a Try block, but is there a better alternative? Any suggestions?

Comment: By default a failed future will result in a Server Error response. You can `.recover` or `.recoverWith` to fallback from such failure to a custom response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually use the following pattern:

```
def compute(id: String) = Action.async { request =>
  val result: Future[SomeType] = compute(id)
  result.map(value => Ok(transform(value, id)))
    .recover { case ex =>
      Logger.error("Something went wrong", ex)
      InternalServerError
    }
}
```

This way the HTTP response code will be `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`, so the caller will be informed. You may also want to add validation on the parameters of the request and return a `400 BAD REQUEST` etc.

Comment: The recover block requires a partial function. Hence request you to change it to case ex =>